# Loading image files as a ndarray in efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of images in a directory and want to make a single ndarray of those images like CIFAR-10. I have written a brute-force way to do so. However it will get really slow if the number of images are large.

```py
def dataLoader(data_path):
    data = np.empty([1,1200,900,3]) # size of an image is 1200*900 with RGB
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(data_path):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
            target = cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_path, filename))
            data = np.concatenate([data, target.reshape([1,1200,900,3])], axis=0)
            print(i, end='\r')
            i += 1
    return data
```

I am checking the progression by printing loop count. As I see that, it is fairly quick at first 50 iterations but it gets slower and slower as it iterates. I suppose it is due to the numpy concatenation. Is there better way to do so?

I also really appreciate if there is a method to save the ndarray so that I don't need to build the ndarray every time. Currently, I'm using `numpy.save`.

Comment: Collect the images in a list, and do one concatenate at the end.  Repeated concatenates like this are slow.

Comment: @hpaulj's advice is spot on.  I would change the second part of his comment to "Repeated concatenates like this are *very* slow."  Each time you do that, you are copying *all* the previous images, so the time complexity of your code is O(n²) where n is the number of images.